# sequence of function $f_n(x)= \sin(n\pi x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$f_n(x):[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f_n(x)= \sin(n\pi x)$$  if $x\in [0,1/n]$, and $$f_n(x)=0$$ if $x\in (1/n,1]$ Then

1. It does not converge pointwise.
2. It  converges pointwise but the limit is not continous.
3. It  converges pointwise but not uniformly.
4. It  converges uniformly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint for your problem:

Note that given an $n$ you will always be able to find a $c \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ such that $f_n(c) = 1$.

Comment: we can chose $c={1\over 2n}\in[0,{1\over n}]$